# Problems opening modal bottom sheet

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:expenses_app/widgets/new_transaction.dart';
import 'package:expenses_app/widgets/transaction_list.dart';
import 'models/transactions.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

main() => runApp(ExpensesApp());

class ExpensesApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<ExpensesApp> createState() => _ExpensesAppState();
}

class _ExpensesAppState extends State<ExpensesApp> {
  final List<Transactions> userTransactions = [
    Transactions(
      id: "t1",
      title: "New Shoes",
      amount: 69.99,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
    Transactions(
      id: "t2",
      title: "Weekly Groceries",
      amount: 13.56,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    ),
  ];

  void addNewTransaction(String txTitle, double txAmount) {
    final newTx = Transactions(
      id: DateTime.now().toString(),
      title: txTitle,
      amount: txAmount,
      date: DateTime.now(),
    );

    setState(() {
      userTransactions.add(newTx);
    });
  }

  void startAddNewTransaction(BuildContext ctx) {
    showModalBottomSheet(
      context: ctx,
      builder: (_) {
        return NewTransactions(addNewTransaction);
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Expenses App"),
          backgroundColor: Colors.pink[900],
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.add),
              onPressed: () => startAddNewTransaction(context),
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Card(
                  child: Text("Chart"),
                ),
              ),
              TransactionList(userTransactions),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerFloat,
        floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
          onPressed: () => startAddNewTransaction(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Guys, i'm having a problem trying to create a modal in the floating action button and in   the app bar, i've already created the list that displays the transactions, the function that add a new transaction, and the function that create a modal,plus i've already deployed that function in the floating action button and app bar, but it's not working. What i'm i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

We can't tell what this 'NewTransactions' methods return because you shared incomplete code. ShowModalBottomSheet functions, on the other hand, must never return null.

I tried returning conatiner from showModalBottomSheet, and it worked perfectly.

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  context: ctx,
  builder: (_) {
     return Container(
       child: Text('This is bottom sheet'),
     );
  },
);
```